# regarding gef selection

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef, draw2d

I am new to GEF. I would like to post some doubts here.
I have created a rectangle figure on the graphical editor. Now I am unable to select that 
figure. In order to select a figure, do I need to use the edit policies and commands?
Also the delete,redo and undo actions can that all be used in a view without an editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling selection is done using edit policies. Since you are new to GEF, you can check out [my tutorial](http://www.vainolo.com/tutorials/) on the subject. You can also read more information from the [sources I have found](http://www.vainolo.com/useful-links/).

Good luck!

Comment: I have the same problem, The tutorial is great, but can you provide a short answer to why selection might not be working? Or, maybe a link to a specific lesson we could have a look at?

Comment: @Willem [Part 7](http://www.vainolo.com/2011/07/07/creating-a-gef-editor-%E2%80%93-part-7-moving-elements-and-direct-editing/) of my tutorial shows how to activate selection when a new edit policy is added to the parent. If you have a specific question ask it on SO and if I know the answer I'll be glad to help

Comment: @Vainolo: The problem I had disappeared when I added DefaultEditDomain.  After analyzing it a bit I thought that the selection started to work because the domain provides the selection tool by default.  I was satisfied that it is the correct solution, so I stopped further exploration.  Thank you.